# Python cmd stop terminal from showing stderr or stdout

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmd

Original Title: Python cmd stop terminal from showing running lines

I could not research this as well as I usually do because I am not sure of the proper terminology to describe what I am trying to stop.(The answer turns out to be stderr)

I have written a small python program that runs files in their native software. I am using Linux so the command is

`opener ="open" if sys.platform == "darwin" else "xdg-open"
 subprocess.call([opener, winner])`

where winner is the file path to be opened. As an interface, I am using the CMD package. Everything runs fine and as expected.

The problem I have is in the terminal. This is where I am unsure what to call it.  After the `subprocess.call` is ran, the terminal shows what it is doing to open the file.  It ends up being about 60 lines depending on what it is opening.

I have three questions:

1. What do you call the terminal lines for it processing a file opening?
2. How do I stop these lines from showing up.  I do not need specific code, just a direction to go.  I realize that there may be no way to do this from python, but I hope there is.
3. This is a generic question about python packages. The [cmd docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html#cmd.Cmd) says that this is "useful for test harnesses, administrative tools, and prototypes that will later be wrapped in a more sophisticated interface." But it gives no other interface options.  Have I met the limitations of cmd? And if so, what command line interface package should I use to solve this problem. (Unfortunately, I do not think I am good enough with python yet to make a full blown gui)

`def start_winner(lst): #starts a file link or a random one from a list
    winner=random.choice(lst)
    opener ="open" if sys.platform == "darwin" else "xdg-open"
    subprocess.call([opener, winner])`

Comment: redirect stdout to dev/null to suppress the output

Comment: did u tried subprocess.call([opener, winner], shell=True)?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I tried unsuccessfully. I am getting a error AttributeError: Cmd instance has no __call__ method
(which is my fault). I am trying to do class First(cmd.Cmd([[[path]]])): which the docs say.

Comment: doing a sys.stdout(path, w) takes away the cmd prompt

Comment: I meant in your subprocess call, `call(([opener, winner],stdout=open(os.devnull,"w"))`, how are you combining  call with the cmd lib?

Comment: @SrikanthBhandary, that method gives me a Synopsis and does not open the file

Comment: cmd also takes a `stdout` parameter

Comment: @PadraicCunningham how would you add the parameter. That is what I thought you meant originally, but I have not been able to figure it out.  Adding the `call([opener, winner],stdout=open(os.devnull,"w"))` did not work

Comment: You need to add the code you are using, i don't see how you are using the cmd lib. Redirecting stdout should definitely have worked using call unless in fact you are seeing stderr in which case `f=open(os.devnull,"w");call(([opener, winner],stdout=f,stderr=f)`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham the last comment worked. Thanks for your help! I added the code before I read it.

Comment: No worries, the output must have been coming from stderr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is 100% @PadraicCunningham. If he post an answer, up vote his instead.

The answer to the questions:

1) The command output was the stderr (could have easily been the stdout). If you are unsure of the difference, [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) and [link](http://www.jstorimer.com/blogs/workingwithcode/7766119-when-to-use-stderr-instead-of-stdout)

2) I changed my start function to

`def start_winner(lst): #starts a file link or a random one from a list
    winner=random.choice(lst)
    f=open(os.devnull,"w")
    opener ="open" if sys.platform == "darwin" else "xdg-open"
    subprocess.call([opener, winner], stdout=f, stderr=f)`

3) No, CMD was not the problem, my lack of understanding outputs was.